# Downgrade Android N beta to M

Tags: 7.0-nougat, android-beta-program

I opted into the N beta and installed it via OTA. Now I want to downgrade back to M and opted out of the beta. The page says that the downgrade should automatically come via OTA, but my device (Nexus 5X) doesn't seem to see any available updates (downgrades).

Should this be instant or can it take a few hours to get the OTA?

Answer (score 3):

Ok solved it.

I opened [g.co/androidbeta](http://g.co/androidbeta) **directly** in Chrome **on the device**, opted back in and out again. Did it via a Desktop browser the first time and didn't work.

Comment: It should be noted that downgrading wipes your device so any data will be lost. Ensure you have backed up anything important before accepting the OTA to downgrade.